# how to get rules and their params with value sonarqube plugin api

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am trying to developing sonar plugin. But i couldnt get rule with params. 
Here my custom rule.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <rule>
       <key>custom-rule-key</key>
       <name>custom rule</name>
       <configKey>custom-rule-key</configKey>
       <description>this is custom rule</description>
       <priority>MINOR</priority>
        <param>
           <key>the-param-key</key>
           <tag>style</tag>
           <tag>security</tag>
           <description>
          <![CDATA[the param-description]]>
            </description>
            <defaultValue>42</defaultValue>
        </param>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

I can see it on sonarqube interface and i can change param value from interface. But as i mentioned, i couldnt reach rule and value of param from code. Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using ? Which API are you using ?

Comment: SonarQube 5.4 and dependency

               <dependency>
   <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
   <version>5.4</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you need to load the rule configuration from scanners ("Sensor" extension point). In this case the component [org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.4/apidocs/index.html?org/sonar/api/batch/rule/ActiveRules.html) must be used and injected in your sensor.

Comment: I got it with org.sonar.api.profiles.RulesProfile (rulesProfile
    .getActiveRulesByRepository(" ");) as you said. But Now i need quality profiles. I can get active rules with parameters but i think only rules belogs to default quality profile are coming. How to get active rules by quaility profiles?

Comment: I didn't mention the class RulesProfile but ActiveRules. That's the way to get the effective rules of the Quality profiles associated to the current project.

Comment: when i set sonar.profile in sonar-project.properties file, i can get active rules with this profile. Rulesprofile is injected in sensor.  rulesProfile .getActiveRulesByRepository(" "); is working for me. Thank you.